# Read user rights using VBscript

Tags: vbscript, privileges

I'm trying to determine whether a user (the one running the script, with or without run as) has certain user rights policies applied. Since **secedit /analyze** refers only to the actual setting and ignores privilege propagation by group membership, it is useless in this case.

I'm referring to these privileges:
SeTcbPrivilege
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SeTcbPrivilege, but look at this [article](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/74620/jsi-tip-3301-how-can-i-report-the-privileges-granted-to-users-or-groups.html) abut how you can determine whether a user has the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege privilege. Basically it talks about how you can use Showpriv.exe from the Windows 2000 Server resource kit

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to scripting, you can get user rights report as well as many other security reports with  Quest's [reporter](http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/reporter).

We use this tool in our company for security compliance reporting and discovery users privileges.